# Lightning: Unable to create new Contact or Account when nested with Opportunity and Contact/Account Creation

Tags: lightning-experience

There is an edge case where you can't create a new Contact or Account in the process of creating a new Opportunity. Here are the steps to reproduce:

(1) Click New Opportunity.

[image: New Opportunity]

(2) The New Opportunity modal appears.

[image: New Opportunity modal]

(3) Click inside Account Name and select New Account.

[image: Select New Account]

(4) The New Account modal appears.

[image: New Account modal]

(5) Now I click into my Custom Field "Referral Source", which is just a Lookup field into Contacts, and the "+ New Contacts" link does not appear in the drop down.

[image: Contacts dropdown]

This also happens if I try to create a Contact first (from the New Opportunity modal) and then try to create a new Account -- the "+ New Account" button isn't there.

How can I get the "+ New Contact" and the "+ New Account" options to appear in this type of nested record creation?

Comment: Do you have the create access on Contact Object?

Comment: Yes. I'm the System Administrator. Also, as I mentioned in the question, within the Opportunity modal, I could click "+ New Contact" but in the Contact modal I can't click "+ New Account." So I'm able to access the "New Contact" modal too.

Comment: Yes, I got you. Salesforce is not allowing more than one level. I have never come across any setting related to that. Let's see what others have to say.

Comment: Thanks @sanketkumar. I'm guessing that this isn't allowed because I haven't seen a setting like this either, but I thought I'd put it out there.